# How can I tell whether I am close to an OutOfMemoryError using jmap?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory, jmap

I am trying to understand which values I should examine in jmap outpout to detect whether JVM is close to throwing an OutOfMemoryError.

e.g. Could in *`jmap -heap pid`* be a combination of values (which are close or have reached 100%)?

Answer (score 0):

`jmap -heap pid`

has a field named `Heap Usage`:

```
Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 560988160 (535.0MB)
   used     = 193192264 (184.24250030517578MB)
   free     = 367795896 (350.7574996948242MB)
   34.43785052433192% used
From Space:
   capacity = 40370176 (38.5MB)
   used     = 40357616 (38.48802185058594MB)
   free     = 12560 (0.0119781494140625MB)
   99.96888792359984% used
To Space:
   capacity = 52953088 (50.5MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 52953088 (50.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 783286272 (747.0MB)
   used     = 35294904 (33.65984344482422MB)
   free     = 747991368 (713.3401565551758MB)
   4.506003138530685% used
```

So you can see the usage percentages.

Comment: Which value should I look at? Can you provide an example output just before reaching an OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: You should check the sum of percentages, specially OldGeneration. Heap is cleared on GC cycles, so it is hard to say when is just before. But if your old gen is above maybe %90-95 you can suspect.